# Fix the width of a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have the following LinearLayout below. I use it for a row in a ListView.

I have set the Textview's weight to 1 so they should all be of equal width.

The problem is when some of the textviews have more characters in, the width of the textview changes. This has an overall effect on how the ListView appears, as in each row the data in not lined up correctly. (i have headings above the ListView).

when some of the TextViews have more text in them, there is still space either side of the text and the textview just gets bigger, which i don't want as i've set the weights to 1 each.

Is there a way of fixing the width of each textview so it doesn't change according to the length of text in it?

thanks in advance

Matt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowstarttimeweeksum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowplannedcallsweeksum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowncrsweeksum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowqasweeksum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowplannedhoursweeksum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2:33"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowactualcallsweeksum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowactualhourssweeksum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2:01" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is it possible to add some screenshots? :-)

Comment: add weightsum="7"  in your linerlayout and width="0dp", it will solve the issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One small change and your problem is solved

change width of all `TextView` from `wrap_content` to `0dp`

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Whenever you will set height/width to `0dp`, it will manage height/width of view as per `android:layout_weight`

Comment: In Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4, no property called `android: layout_weight` could be found for my TextView. I'm using ConstraintLayout as the container. What to do in that case?