# How to make textViews fill a row width?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am preparing a tic tac game :
Initially all 9 cells are empty.Upon starting game as i enter number, the width of the cell change dynamically.How to prevent that?

[image: width of Last column becomes equal spaced as i enter a number in third column]

My xml codeof 9 cells:

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:theme="@style/MyTextViewStyle">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        tools:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        tools:text="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        tools:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        tools:text="4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        tools:text="5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        tools:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        tools:text="7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        tools:text="8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        tools:text="" />

</GridLayout>
```

PS : I don't want to use Table Layout,Set of Horizontal and vertical Linear Layouts or any other views. Please tell me how to do it in GridLayout itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each `TextView`, set the `layout_width` to 0dp. Initially, the `TextView` will be 0 pixel large, but they will equally fill the remaining space as a result of : `android:layout_columnWeight="1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34653025/9093967). You only need to change the following piece on every TextView:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put a fixed weight on each column of your row.
To do this you would have to assign in each component in this case Textview,
the pes they are going to have in the row. If your row is going to have 2 components you could assign to the value of the sum of weight in `weight_sum = "1"` and then in each component you assign the weight that you will have if you wanted them equal for example you would, `layout_weight = 0.5` .So in this way you would have fixed each component width inside the container.

I hope it has been of your help.

Your Code:

> ```
> <GridLayout
>     android:id="@+id/grid_layout_id"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="center"
>     android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
>     android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
>     android:rowCount="3"
>     android:columnCount="3"
>     weight_sum="3"
>     android:padding="10dp"
>     android:theme="@style/MyTextViewStyle">
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView1"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         tools:text="1" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView2"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         tools:text="2" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView3"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         tools:text="" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView4"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         tools:text="4" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView5"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         tools:text="5" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView6"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         tools:text="" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView7"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         tools:text="7" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView8"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         tools:text="8" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView9"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         tools:text="" />
>
> </GridLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have used `android:layout_columnWeight="1"` but also used `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. As mentioned in this [post](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html), there is no need to use layout_width parameters in GridLayout and thus, should be avoided.

Try setting your layout_width and layout_height to any fixed value say 10 dp, then android would rather use Layout_columnWeight and assign equal portion to each textview. Also, read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954438/how-to-support-layout-columnweight-and-layout-rowweight-in-pre-api-21) to allow backward compatibility of layout_width.